# How to print structs and arrays?

Tags: rust

How do I print structs and arrays in Rust? Other languages are able to print structs and arrays directly.

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
    b: i32
}
```

and

```
let arr: [i32; 10] = [1; 10];
```

Comment: Rust has a different philosophy than Go: where Go is "batteries included", Rust is "do not pay for what you do not use". Thus, if you wish to print `MyStruct`, you have to ask the compiler to include the code to print it (or code it yourself).

Comment: @MatthieuM. this is actually the right answer (with a great context in relation to Go).  Post and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You want to implement the `Debug` trait on your struct. Using `#[derive(Debug)]` is the easiest solution. Then you can print it with `{:?}`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct{
    a: i32,
    b: i32
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct{ a: 10, b: 20 };
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

Comment: can we use Debug trait for arrays?

Comment: @tez the `Debug` trait is [already implemented for many types](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html), including arrays from 0 to 32 items, as well as slices and `Vec` of any length. The important thing is that the item *inside the container* must also implement `Debug`.

Comment: It is also possible to pretty print in debug mode using the same trait `#[derive(Debug)]` as shown in above answer, while replacing `{:?}` with `{:#?}` in `println!` macro.
  
Details can be found in [Rust Book Ch-5](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-02-example-structs.html#adding-useful-functionality-with-derived-traits)

Answer (score 37):

As [mdup says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253540/155423), you can use `Debug`, but you can also use the [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait.

All types can derive (automatically create) the `fmt::Debug` implementation as `#[derive(Debug)]`, but `fmt::Display` must be manually implemented.

You can create a custom output:

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
    b: i32
}

impl std::fmt::Display for MyStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "(value a: {}, value b: {})", self.a, self.b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = MyStruct { a: 0, b: 0 };

    println!("Used Display: {}", test);    
}
```

Shell:

```
Used Display: (value a: 0, value b: 0)
```

For more information, you can look at the [`fmt` module documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits).

Answer (score 13):

As no one here explicitly answers for arrays, to print out an array you need to specify the `{:?}`, also used to print debug output

```
let val = 3;
let length = 32; // the maximum that can be printed without error
let array1d = [val; length];
let array2d = [array1d; length]; // or [[3; 32]; 32];
let array3d = [array2d; length]; // or [[[3; 32]; 32]; 32];
```

However arrays where `length > 32` will exit with an error:

```
let length = 33;
let array1d = [3; length];
println("{:?}", array1d);

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[{integer}; 33]: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
--> src\main.rs:6:22
|
|     println!("{:?}", array1d);
|                      ^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `[{integer}; 33]`
```

Longer arrays can be printed out with the approach from this answer: [Implement Debug trait for large array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901965/implement-debug-trait-for-large-array-type)

Answer (score 10):

If you want your output to be **formatted properly** with *indentation*, you can use `{:#?}`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct{
    a: i32,
    b: i32
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct{ a: 10, b: 20 };
    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

Output:

```rust
MyStruct {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually just `{:?}` is sufficient.

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let complete = &a[..];
println! ("{:?}", a);
println! ("{:?}", complete);
```

Comment: This is not true for structs. It only works for arrays.

Comment: And it only works for arrays whose inner elements implement the `Debug` trait.

Answer (score 0):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
 struct Rectangle{
       width: u32,
       height: u32,
  }

fn main(){
   let rec = Rectangle{
      width: 50,
      height: 30,
   };

   println!("The rectangle {:?} ", rec);
   println!("The area of the rectangle is {} pixels", 
   area_rectangle(&rec));
}

fn area_rectangle(rectangle: &Rectangle) -> u32{
    rectangle.width * rectangle.height
}
```