# Rust "the trait `std::array::LengthAtMost32` is not implemented"

Tags: arrays, rust, traits, display

How come this works,

```
let a = Box::new([2; 10]);
println!( "foo {:?}", a );
```

But this doesn't,

```
let a = Box::new([2; 100]);
println!( "foo {:?}", a );
```

Why does an array's length determine the trait implementations? The error seems unrelated to the question. Conversely, how can achive the effect I desire with the above code.

The error is reproduced is:

```
error[E0277]: arrays only have std trait implementations for lengths 0..=32
 --> ./test.rs:4:27
  |
4 |     println!( "foo {:?}", a );
  |                           ^ the trait `std::array::LengthAtMost32` is not implemented for `[{integer}; 100]`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `[{integer}; 100]`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `std::boxed::Box<[{integer}; 100]>`
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement Debug trait for large array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901965/implement-debug-trait-for-large-array-type)

Comment: not really, I ask why in this question. Why is that this is a constraint? Why was length=32 picked? I want to understand it not just be told it's impossible.

Comment: Ah okay. There's a bit about the rationale for why some N was chosen on the [documentation for the array module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html). I'm not sure there's a deeper reason for why 32 was chosen other than "it seems big enough most of the time".

Comment: @Ryan1729 thanks that actually had exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 6):

From the docs on [`array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html)

> This limitation on the size N exists because **Rust does not yet support code that is generic over the size of an array type.** [Foo; 3] and [Bar; 3] are instances of same generic type [T; 3], but [Foo; 3] and [Foo; 5] are entirely different types. **As a stopgap, trait implementations are statically generated up to size 32.**

This answers both of my questions,

- Rust lacks generics of the size of an array type,
- 32 was a just an accepted compromise and there is no strong technical reason for it. It seems as if this trait is named as such because it's [applied with macro.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#398)

And from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30901965/124486), there is no acceptable workaround for this. It's just a hard limitation.