# How to print an array and a vector?

Tags: arrays, vector, printing, rust

I'm playing with Rust and I wonder how I can print an array and a vector.

```
let a_vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let an_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
```

I want to print on the screen and the result should be something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

In python it is:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
print lst
```

and printing it would show:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253422/how-to-print-structs-and-arrays ?

Comment: Additionally, please read [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask). In this example, you should include *what you have already tried*. It would be even better to include a [MCVE](/help/mcve). I'd also **highly** recommend reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), which the team has spent a lot of time on.

Comment: thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
println!("{:?}", a_vector);
println!("{:?}", an_array);
```

The `{:?}` is used to print types that implement the Debug trait. A regular `{}` would use the Display trait which Vec and arrays don't implement.

Comment: That works only for arrays up to 32 ("arrays only have std trait implementations for lengths 0..=32"). Is there an easy way to print content of longer arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
fn main() {
```

let v = vec![12; 4];
let v1 = vec![7; 5];

//1. In general, the `{}` will be automatically replaced with any
// arguments in order of their placement. These will be stringified.

println!("{:?}", v);

println!("First vector: {0:?} and Second vector: {1:?}  ", v, v1);

//Results above
//[12, 12, 12, 12]

//First vector: [12, 12, 12, 12] and Second vector: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

//2.With  Positional arguments

```
 println!("{0:?}", v);

 println!("First vector: {0:?} and Second vector: {1:?}  ", v, v1);
```

// Results above

//[12, 12, 12, 12]

//First vector: [12, 12, 12, 12] and Second vector: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

//2.You could assign variables for  Positional arguments as well

```
 println!("{var1:?}", var1 =v);

 println!("First vector: {var1:?} and Second vector: {var2:?}  ", var1=v, var2=v1);
```

// Results above

//[12, 12, 12, 12]

//First vector: [12, 12, 12, 12] and Second vector: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

}