# Error: `Info` doesn't implement `Display` (required by {})

Tags: rust

I got error: `Info doesn't implement Display (required by {}):11` while running this code:

```rust
struct Info<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let john = Info {
        name: "John",
        age: 32,
    };
        println!("{}", john);
}
```

I have no idea what im doing wrong. Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print structs and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253422/how-to-print-structs-and-arrays)

Answer (score 22):

In order for a struct to be formatable via `"{}"` format specifier it needs  to implement the `std::fmt::Display` trait.
Therefore, to make your code compile, you need to `impl Display for Info`:

```rust
impl std::fmt::Display for Info<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(fmt, "My name is {} and I'm {} years old.", self.name, self.age)
    }
}
```

Note that `Display` trait is idiomatically used for user-facing representations.

Alternatively, you could use `"{:?}"` format specifier and `#[derive(Debug)]` annotation on your type to use formatter provided by `std::fmt::Debug` trait:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Info<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let john = Info {
        name: "John",
        age: 32,
    };
    println!("{:?}", john);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Ivan C, this helped a lot coming from mostly python and js, where you just take it for granted console or print and get something logged out