# Pretty print struct in Rust

Tags: rust

[How to print structs and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253422/how-to-print-structs-and-arrays) - how does one pretty print a rust struct or any data type?

Sure, one can write the custom Debug method. But is there some way which enables the print by default?

One option is to use: https://docs.rs/pretty-trait/latest/pretty_trait/

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in the linked question? "Using `#[derive(Debug)]` is the easiest solution."

Comment: It is default print and not pretty print.

Comment: No, I don't mean to self answer. But I am looking for a different way without using any other trait (is possible).

Comment: according to [one of the comments on your linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253422/how-to-print-structs-and-arrays#comment97289268_30253540), you can use `{:#?}` for moderately prettier formatting of the `Debug` trait

Comment: _"is there some way which enables the print by default?"_ -- No, that's exactly what `Debug` is for in the first place.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When you implement `Debug`, Rust provides "pretty printing" with `{:#?}`. From the [`std::fmt` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0):

> - `#` - This flag indicates that the “alternate” form of printing should be used. The alternate forms are:
>
>   - `{:#?}` - pretty-print the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) formatting (adds linebreaks and indentation)
>   - [others omitted]

Example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: &'static str,
    age: u8,
    hobbies: Vec<&'static str>,
}

fn main() {
    let peter = Person {
        name: "Jesse",
        age: 49,
        hobbies: vec!["crosswords", "sudoku"],
    };
    println!("{:#?}", peter);
}
```

Output:

```
Person {
    name: "Jesse",
    age: 49,
    hobbies: [
        "crosswords",
        "sudoku",
    ],
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=48db398be69a4658fc8bffa89a57e313)

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. Any idea why this is not the default format option?

Comment: People often want to print debugging info in log messages, which works best when it's all on one line.

Comment: @VikasGoel It's very verbose. I do all my debugging via log statements. If the `Vec`s that I print out are all pretty-printed, I would be wading through several hundreds of lines of output rather than less than one page.

Comment: Doesn't this not work when usiing third-party creates, unless you change their code?v Third-party crates are often the source of difficulty. Would be great if this was easier.

Comment: It works with third-party crates.